# How to make safe cast using generics in C#?

Tags: generics, c#-3.0, constraints, type-conversion, type-constraints

I want to implement a generic method on a generic class which would allow to cast safely, see example:

```
public class Foo<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    ...
    public IEnumerable<R> SafeCast<R>()
        where T : R
    {
        return this.Select(item => (R)item);
    }
}
```

However, the compiler tells me that `Foo<T>.SafeCast<R>() does not define parameter 'T'`. I understand this message that I cannot specify a constraint on `T` in the method since it is not defined in the method. But how can I specify an inverse constraint?

Comment: What behavior do you expect if T isn't derived from R?

Comment: @Jake: the intention here is that if R is not chosen such that T is convertible to R, then the program fails to compile. For example, you might have a Foo<Exception> f and say f.SafeCast<object>.  If you said f.SafeCast<IOException> then that would fail to compile. Sadly, we do not support this feature.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

C# does not have that kind of constraint.  A constraint has to be of the form "R must be convertible *to* X"; we do not support constraints of the form "R must be convertible *from* X".

Which is unfortunate, since it makes certain scenarios involving contravariant conversions easier.

Scala permits such a constraint, incidentally.

Interestingly enough, you can do what you want with an extension method, but you then have to be redundant when you call it:

```
public static IEnumerable<R> SafeCast<T, R>(this IEnumerable<T> x) where T : R
{
    return x.Cast<R>();
}
```

Now you can say:

```
IEnumerable<Giraffe> giraffes = whatever;
IEnumerable<Animal> animals = giraffes.SafeCast<Giraffe, Animal>();
```

In C# 4 your code will be largely unnecessary; `IEnumerable<T>` is safely covariant in T in C# 4 *if T is a reference type*.

Answer (score 0):

`public IEnumerable<R> SafeCast<T,R>() where T : R` is the signature I think you need to do this. Does that not do what you want?

Comment: No, that redeclares T. The OP wants the outer T.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Will not delete my answer so people can learn from your comment and why my suggestion is NOT a solution. :-)